# python sum of memory usage of every variable

Tags: python, variables, memory, memory-management, task

I need to solve a problem and I definetly don't have any idea how to solve it. I have a program that have more than 2 variables. Every variable takes memory (bytes) and I need to calculate sum of that bytes (i think that only way is to use sys.getsizeof, ctypes.string_at and struct.unpack). So, for example

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, input().split(" "))
if x1 > x2:
    resX = x1 - x2
    resY = y1 - y2
else:
    resX = x2 - x1
    resY = y2 - y1
k = int(resY/resX)
b = y1 - (k*x1)
if b > 0:
    print("y = {}x + {}".format(k, b))
else:
    print("y = {}x - {}".format(k, abs(b)))
```

There is a lot of vars. If i'll try to do it stupid, result will be `sys.getsizeof(x1) + sys.getsizeof(x2) + sys.getsizeof(x3) ... + sys.getsizeof(b)`. But I need to write a function that will count sum for every amount of vars. Firstly, I don't know how to separate variables (i thought about creating dict and calculating values' memory usage but i really don't know how to separate vars, anyway). 
Could you give me an advice? This task is very specific and I didn't find anything about solving this problem in google. Everywhere programmers just add up every uasge like I showed above.
So, I'll be very glad if you'll state your ideas about that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `locals()` to get the variables in the current scope:

```
import sys

x1, y1, x2, y2 = 1, 2, 3, 4  # map(int, input().split(" "))
if x1 > x2:
    resX = x1 - x2
    resY = y1 - y2
else:
    resX = x2 - x1
    resY = y2 - y1
k = int(resY/resX)
b = y1 - (k*x1)
if b > 0:
    print("y = {}x + {}".format(k, b))
else:
    print("y = {}x - {}".format(k, abs(b)))

local_variables = [(var, sys.getsizeof(obj)) for var, obj in locals().items() if not var.startswith('__') and var not in ['sys',]]
current_size = sum([size for var, size in local_variables])
print('Local variables and sizes: ', local_variables)
print('Total size of local variables:', current_size)
```

Output:

```
y = 1x + 1
Local variables and sizes:  [('b', 28), ('resY', 28), ('k', 28), ('y1', 28), ('y2', 28), ('x2', 28), ('resX', 28), ('x1', 28)]
Total size of local variables: 224
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You've improved my skills